# Marker clusterer bug when dragging the map? (Many markers on google maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I got the many markers solution on my website.

I noticed though that when I drag the map there seams to be an issue if I start dragging the map when holding the mouse over a many-markers icon.

The map zooms in on the position when I release the mouse button. This feature is suppose to be there when I click an icon.. but should´nt be there when I´m trying to drag the map?

It even looks like googles (own?) example has this issue so it might not be my code.
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toomanymarkers/toomanymarkers.html

- Open the link
- Check the "Many markers" box
- Try to drag the map when the mouse is over a "many marker" icon.

Frustrating when the map zooms in when I try to scroll the map sideways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragstart',function(){
      mc.zoomOnClick_=false;});
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mouseup',function(){setTimeout(function(){
      mc.zoomOnClick_=true;},50);});
```

These lines(`mc` is the MarkerClusterer-Instance) should help.

It disables the zoomOnClick-feature when you start dragging the map and re-enables it on mouseup(with a short delay, because `mouseup` fires before `click`)

Comment: Much simpler than diving into the library.

Comment: Sweet! Did´nt think of that. That was a 20sec fix.
I just added that right after I created my insances. I would upvote all answers if I had more reputation :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a side effect of the intended functionality. The library will be detecting the mouseup event and zooming on the marker that was selected by mousedown I imagine.

I suppose the two options that you have are to either disable the zoom on click functionality entirely, or to alter the library yourself (possibly branch it if you think others will use it) to perhaps zoom on a different event, e.g. mousedown.

Comment: Tnx.. if anyone has altered this that reads this, I would be interrested in the code! My described problem works fine on regular google markers. Either zoom on click or drag on drag.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20685193/2942885) from @Dr.Molle will work as long as sources are not minified (mangled names). I had to upgrade to **[MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus)** which provides a method for changing zoom on click. MarkerClustererPlus ist mostly backwards compatible to MarkerClusterer.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
      mc.setZoomOnClick(false);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mouseup',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        mc.setZoomOnClick(true);
    }, 50);
});
```